# Admin Template in Bootstrap+HTML to Include in ANGULAR 14?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have my MVC project, which is developed in Bootstrap HTML from the front,

I want to use the Same Template now in My Angular projects, I have my CSS files, JavaScript files, etc.

I have added them all in the src folder of Angular and given their links in Angular. JSON files, everything works fine except the side navbar, it's not working the way it was working with the old project, it just shows the list of content.

So is this possible to use the bootstrap admin template in angular?
secondly, there is an index.html file in angular is this just like shared-layout or something?

What could be the issue with my navbar not working properly?
I am new to angular

Comment: Probably you now have another/newer version of bootstrap. Did you use npm to install bootstrap?

Comment: No i am just importing external bootstrap libraries which I was using in my old project